# Alamofire can't get request with php

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have got this Swift 4 code

```
let par: Parameters = [
                          "usn":"Murad",
                          "Password":"monkey"
                      ]
Alamofire.request("http://www.web.com/ajax/logreg.php",method: .post,parameters:par,encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).response { response in

    if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
       print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
   }
}
```

And this PHP code

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Now i supposed that this code will print

```
Array(
   "usn":"Murad",
   "Password":"monkey",    
)
```

But instead it prints

```
Array
(
    [(componentTuple_0)] => (componentTuple.1)
)
```

Comment: change encoding and try ?

Comment: That looks like JSON, are you sure your API isn't returning JSON?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Json encoding gives me this error `fAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))
[Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 522672231.598, "Initial Response Time": 522672231.719, "Request Completed Time": 522672231.720, ...`

Comment: JSON requests cannot be received into `$_POST`. If you want to make your Swift code work, you may need to update your PHP code.

Comment: @OOPer but in documentation https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire it says that you should sent post the way i did.

Comment: Ignore it. It's just an **example** which assumes your server accepts and returns JSON. And that **is not your case**. Your app needs to send request which your server can accept and your app needs to decode the response in the way your server encoded. AlamoFire is not the only choice and you can go back with your old code.

Comment: @sakoaskoaso api is working well but your array is not encode from server side right?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
   let par: Parameters = [
                "usn":"Murad",
                "Password":"monkey"
            ]


   Alamofire.request("http://www.web.com/ajax/logreg.php", method: .post, parameters: par as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let JSON):
                //                    print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
                if let response = JSON as? NSMutableDictionary
        {
            callback(response,nil)
        }
        else if let response = JSON2 as? NSDictionary
        {
            callback(response,nil)
        }
        else if JSON2 is NSArray
        {


        }
        else if ((JSON as? String) != nil)
        {

            let userDic : [String : String] = ["quatid":JSON as! String]
            print(userDic)
            callback(userDic as NSDictionary?,nil)

    }

                break

            case .failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                callback(response.result.value as? NSMutableDictionary,error as NSError?)
                break
            }
            }
            .responseString { response in
                print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
        }
```

Comment: What is callback?

Comment: in callback make condition got json , array or string then you can populate and in this code Dictionary Callback get

Answer (score 0):

You are using array of key pairs hence use `.prettyPrinted` formatting.
Hope this snippet will helps

```
     var arrayOfKeyPairs = [[String:Any]]()
     let JSON = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrayOfKeyPairs, options: [.prettyPrinted])
     let jsonPrasatation = String(data: JSON!, encoding: .utf8)
```